# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get' in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to add a multiple choice field to my project app. This field should allow the user for select more than one choice. But I get an error. Before I added the multiple choice field, this part did not give any error. Where is my mistake?

**my views.py**

```
def project_new(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        project = Project()
       ...
        project.lang_choices = form.cleaned_data['select_lang']
        project.save()
        return redirect('projects')
else:
    form = ProjectForm()


  return render(request, 'blog/project_new.html', {'form': form})

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def project_details(request, pk):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/project_detail.html', {'project': project})
```

**my models.py**

```
class ProgrammingLanguage(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
class Project(models.Model):
        ...
        select_langs = models.ManyToManyField(ProgrammingLanguage)
        ...
        slug = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
    ...
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProjectForm(forms.Form):
...
select_lang = forms.ChoiceField(
    label='diller: ',
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProjectForm, self).__init__(args, kwargs)



       self.fields['select_lang'].choices = [(l.id, l.name) for l in ProgrammingLanguage.objects.all()]


class Meta:
    model = Project
    fields = (
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'project_name', 'project_description', 'project_notes', 'select_langs')
```

**And this is my traceback**

```
Internal Server Error: /project/new/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eda/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/eda/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/eda/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/eda/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eda/staj_defteri/project/views.py", line 16, in project_new
    if form.is_valid():
  File "/home/eda/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 183, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/home/eda/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 175, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/home/eda/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 384, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/home/eda/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 396, in _clean_fields
    value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
  File "/home/eda/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 240, in value_from_datadict
    return data.get(name)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
[17/Sep/2018 08:19:35] "POST /project/new/ HTTP/1.1" 500 98194
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback. Where is the error happening?

Comment: Add the traceback to your question.There's no `get` method call in the code you've included here.

Comment: You call the `__init__` with `args` and `kwargs`, not `*args` and `**kwargs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is probably the fact that you call the `super(ProjectForm, self).__init__` with `args`, and `kwargs` as two parameters, *not* with sequence unpacking and dictionary unpacking, like:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['select_lang'].choices = [
        (l.id, l.name) for l in ProgrammingLanguage.objects.all()
    ]
```

In case you call it with `args`, etc. the first parameter will contain a (possibly empty) tuple as `data` parameter. If you then later aim to process the `data`, it will fail to do so.

That being said, I do not understand why you make it a `forms.ChoiceField` here. By default Django will pick a [**`ModelMultipleChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField) field, and also take by default the entire collection of `ProgrammingLanguage` onbjects.

Comment: I have just one more question. I want to display that the user's choices in my project details page. How can I do it in my HTML page?

Comment: You can iterate over the programming languages with `{% for lang in project.select_langs %}` (end with `{% endfor %}`), and thus in the loop for example print `{{ lang }}`.